# The 'dispersion' tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There is a new tag: [dispersion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dispersion), which I just edited. It can, I believe, refer to at least two different things:

1. Measures of spread of a distribution or set of values (e.g. the sd, the interquartile range).
2. The rate at which something (e.g. a new idea, an infection) spreads through a network or a population.

What should be done here?

Comment: It seems to have been created by @Quartz for that [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72937/what-is-the-statistical-efficiency-of-l-moments). Perhaps we should ask him (?) what the tag stands for, & to edit the wiki & excerpt. Note also that the tag will disappear if it isn't used on another question w/i 6 months.

Comment: A third well defined "dispersion" is the unconstrained proportionality constant that's estimated in quasilikelihood.

Answer (score 4):

The [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72937/what-is-the-statistical-efficiency-of-l-moments) that uses [dispersion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dispersion) (x 1) is meaning the bullet number #1:

> Measures of spread of a distribution or set of values (e.g. the sd, the interquartile range).

In my opinion, we already have a tag which covers bullet #2: [epidemiology](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epidemiology) (x 109). I am considering the topic diseases/infection (can't think of a different concrete example for this).

Its excerpt says:

> Epidemiology is the study of the distribution and spread of disease or illness at the population level.

It also has a nice [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/epidemiology/info).

**Proposal**

Change the current [dispersion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dispersion) tag excerpt from:

> Dispersion can refer to at least two things 1) It is a general term for how spread apart values are; 2) It is a term for how fast something spreads through a network

to something in the below lines;

> It is a general term for how spread apart values are. For questions related to disease spread/dispersion content, use the tag epidemiology.

In case another example appears, than we could consider a new tag to it or to adapt the situation to an existing tag (if any). Then, the `dispersion` excerpt would be:

> It is a general term for how spread apart values are. For questions related to disease spread/dispersion content, use the tag epidemiology. For other meanings of dispersion consider using a related tag or creating a new one.

Comment: There are examples of the 2nd bullet that I don't think are covered by epidemiology. E.g. diffusion of innovation. This has quite an extensive literature, partly overlapping with network analysis.

Comment: @Peter, ok (got it). The proposal last paragraph tried to address this extra examples. Do we have question on CV under diffusion of innovation content? If yes, is there any other tag worthy to be used (like epidemiology for dispersion of diseases)? If no, do you think there is a better tag for diffusion of innovation than `dispersion`?

Comment: Added another excerpt suggestion considering your comments. Most important I think is to eliminate the tag subjectivity (i.e. let it be used for just one meaning).

Comment: How about "Diffusion"?

Comment: @Peter, do you think we could proceed with the changing  of current `dispersion` tag excerpt? Or should we wait for other answers/suggestions or more votes on this thread? Tks

Comment: It's been a month, I say go ahead.

Comment: IMHO the current situation with the [dispersion] tag is pretty awful, see the new answer and the comments underneath.

Comment: @amoeba, why is it awful? Misuse?

Comment: The tag whose excerpt begins with "This tag is very ambiguous" is a bad tag and should not exist.

Comment: @amoeba, I don't see it as an awful tag (to me 'awful' is when it leads users to tag/group questions incorrectly), but perhaps it is near useless, which means it does not help grouping questions better than other already existing tags do. I suggest you posting an answer pro burnination, and explaining reasons. I will support it, after all, only 47 Qs in almost 4 years is not very encouraging.

Comment: But this tag does lead users to group questions incorrectly! This is precisely what happens. [Dispersion] tag is used to refer to "spread" and also to refer to the "dispersion parameter in quasilikelihood". And maybe also to refer to epidemiology (not sure). I am not ready to post an answer because I did not look at the existing 47 Qs to figure out what are the most common uses of this tag, and do not have a good suggestion of how to disambiguate this tag for the future.

Comment: @amoeba, a [quick search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdispersion%5D+quasi) did not yield any result in the second usage. Anyway, I have no objections eliminating [tag:dispersion].

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdispersion%5D+glm and there's probably more.

Answer (score 3):

I really think this tag needs to be edited. Dispersion, underdispersion, and overdispersion should be synonyms.

The dispersion parameter $\phi$ was coined by Wedderburn in 79 in his paper on quasilikelihood and this has been a term that has continued to be used in the majority of literature and software. It refers specifically to parametric estimation and certain classes of models. Overdispersion is simply $\phi > 1$ and conversely for underdispersion.

A separate tag called "spread" could be created for robust analogues of "variance" including median absolute deviation, or trimmed mean squared error, or the like. These should not be conflated. Despite that, I concede the current wikipedia page on "statistical dispersion" mostly addresses what I am calling "spread" here. Yet, it does not cite the Wedderburn paper, nor any relevant literature on dispersion, and the cited literature mostly refers to "spread" rather than "dispersion" for the concept of robust/alternative measures of variance.

I agree that questions addressing the epidemiologic concept should simply be tagged "epidemiology".

Comment: Any solution would need to address what people are using this tag for IN PRACTICE. There are only 47 questions tagged with [dispersion]. How many are about "spread"? How many are about "dispersion" as the parameter in quasilikelihood? How many are about epidemiology? Without this information it is impossible to say what the optimal solution is.

Comment: By the way, there is also [variability] tag with the excerpt "Variability or dispersion describes how a variable's values are spread out".